# How to get HTML to show 80,000 pixel image?

Tags: html, image, plot

I have a plot that's 80,000 pixels wide in `.png` format, with 200 pixel height. I can't view it with a normal viewer. However my goal is to be able to view it in a `.html` file. I encoded it into `base64` and saved it into a `.html` but it isn't showing. All that shows is that icon with a piece of paper with a tear in the middle. If I put a 500 pixel wide image in there it displays properly.

What do I have to do to get monstrously large images to display in `html`?

Comment: There is a limit for HTML attribute value length - 65536. I guess that is why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Jaa-c How to get around it? Maybe put two huge images right next to each other on same row?

Answer (score 0):

Do in the way Google Map does (did, before goes vector). Checkout Google Map API about for custom map.